# How to query_post custom posts within default taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, query-posts

I'm trying to query_post custom posts. It works very good with custom taxonomy, but not with default "category" taxonomy. I tried using "category_name" and "tax_query", but it doesn't work for me.

My code is:

```
  $c_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'category',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => 'furniture'
        )
    )
);

// The Query
wp_reset_postdata();

query_posts( $c_args );
```

I get no results. 
As I said - it works with custom taxonomy, but I need to use "Custom Permalinks" plugin, which doesn't work with custom taxonomy.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `query_posts( $c_args );` NO NO NO. Don't ever use `query_posts` you should go back and rewrite your code using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I still had no posts even with WP_Query, but after some tests on the query itself (var_dump($query)) I found my fault. I used [ReOrder Post Within Categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reorder-post-within-categories/) plugin (which is really great!). After switching from custom taxonomy to normal category I forgot to update some settings of this plugin. Now it seems to work.

Comment: Glad your problem is resolved. To extend your knowledge, go and check out [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/31545).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of query_posts().

```
$cpt_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'furniture'
        )
    )
);
$cpt_query = new WP_Query( $cpt_args );
```